# Build m2m relationship for parents to children and siblings

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

To describe my problem let's assume there is a model class `Person`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    sex = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=(
            ('F', 'female'),
            ('M', 'male')
        )
    )
    relatives = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

A person can have many (or none) relatives of these types:

- parents
- children
- siblings
- halfsiblings (maternal or paternal)

In order to describe the relationship type we need another model class and the option `through`, which in this case will require also the option `symmetrical=False`.

The relation parent-child is indeed asymmetrical, however the siblings relation is symmetrical.
I'm looking for an elegant and clear solution to overcome the dilemma between the true symmetrical relation of siblings and the asymmetrical relation of parents and children.

Adapting the field `relatives` and adding additional model class results in:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    relatives = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        through='Relatedness',
        symmetrical=False,
        blank=True
    )

class Relatedness(models.Model):
    RELATIONSHIPS = (
        ('PA', 'parent'),
        ('SI', 'sibling'),
        ('MH', 'maternal halfsibling'),
        ('PH', 'paternal halfsibling'),
    )
    source = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='source')
    target = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='target')
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=RELATIONSHIPS)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('source', 'target')
```

What I need is:

- to show all relatives for a person
- to implement constraints that there are no weird combinations like if A is mother of B, C is mother of D, then B and D can't be maternal halfsiblings
- to implement managers or querysets to show children, parents and siblings for a person

Do you have any other ideas how this can be implemented in a clean way? Is the approach with `relatives` good or maybe I should split that into two different fields `parents` and `siblings`?

There are no other relationships beyond the mentioned ones. The relationships can't always be determined from the existing entries, for example A and B are paternal halfsiblings but their parents are not present in the database.

Comment: What about self ForeignKey?

Comment: @beCurious be verbose, please!

Comment: sorry for that. I mean  each relationship can be independent foreignkey.
like, not 'relatives', `parent = models.ManyToMany(... sibling = models ManyToMany`. if Relatedness Model is bigger then bigger, you can have query problem to find someone is A's parent.

Comment: I think if independent ManyToMany (before i said foreignkey), will make your query easier. If you want to find person who doesn't have parent, you can use just `Person.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)`.

Comment: @beCurious A person can have more than one parent, in fact it can have two parents. Also a person can have many siblings (halfsiblings included). That means, splitting the `relatives` into two fields introduces two m2m relations, not two 1:n relations.

Comment: Our comments came almost simultaneously. Yes, that's what I was thinking and asking. But that will introduce other issues, like assuring that if A is parent of B, they can't be siblings. Eventually I could do that with `limit_choices_to`.

Comment: I understand what's your point. (I'm not good at english. forgive me).
But, I did not understand one thing. if A is parent of B, they cannot be siblings. (but system can). This part, `parent field`, `siblings field`, `half_siblings field` are just bucket. If you want to Model is block if A is parent of B and A is siblings of B? I think you can solve that on logical code. Did i understand your point?

Comment: Oh i got it. I have to more think about it. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't *have* to use a `ManyToManyField` when you use an explicit intermediate model - you can just omit the `ManyToManyField` in `Person` (you'll still have the proper relationships in your `Relatedness` model), and provide your own related accessors in `Person` (using properties and related queryset lookups).

Comment: The idea with omitting the `ManyToManyFiel` is good. I have tried it and could implement `cached_property` methods for retrieving all relatives, parents, children, siblings. It is stilly tricky to validate that there aren't impossible relations.